# Connecting of Database per each JFrame

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-connection

I have created this Automated Library. And I need to know how to connect my Database per each JFrame.
This is my main method:

```
package com.Student.GUI;

public class Student_HomePage extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField searchBox;
private static String results[];
private static Connection conn;
private static String searchText;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
                conn = db.openConnection();
                Student_HomePage frame = new Student_HomePage();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setBounds(400,150,599,489);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Student_HomePage() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("D:\\ITC302-Core Java\\java_workspace\\Pictures\\lala.png"));
    setTitle("LookBook");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 599, 489);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnHome = new JButton("Home");
    btnHome.setFont(new Font("Plantagenet Cherokee", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    btnHome.setEnabled(false);
    btnHome.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnHome.setBorder(null);
    btnHome.setBounds(144, 24, 95, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnHome);

    JButton btnAuthors = new JButton("Authors");
    btnAuthors.setFont(new Font("Plantagenet Cherokee", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    btnAuthors.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnAuthors.setBorder(null);
    btnAuthors.setBounds(241, 24, 95, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnAuthors);

    JButton btnBooks = new JButton("Books");
    btnBooks.setFont(new Font("Plantagenet Cherokee", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    btnBooks.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnBooks.setBorder(null);
    btnBooks.setBounds(338, 24, 95, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnBooks);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setText("|");
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setBounds(227, 11, 26, 57);
    contentPane.add(textArea);

    JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_1.setText("|");
    textArea_1.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    textArea_1.setEditable(false);
    textArea_1.setBounds(325, 11, 26, 57);
    contentPane.add(textArea_1);

    searchBox = new JTextField();
    searchBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String temp = new String(searchBox.getText());
            searchText = temp;
        }
    });
    searchBox.setColumns(10);
    searchBox.setBounds(37, 210, 148, 25);
    contentPane.add(searchBox);

    JTextArea textArea_2 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_2.setText("Search title of books,\r\nauthors or genre");
    textArea_2.setFont(new Font("Plantagenet Cherokee", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    textArea_2.setBounds(37, 248, 188, 40);
    contentPane.add(textArea_2);

    JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
    btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String temp = new String(searchBox.getText());
            btnSearchActionPerformed(e, temp);
        }
    });
    btnSearch.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\ITC302-Core Java\\java_workspace\\Pictures\\searchIcon.png"));
    btnSearch.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnSearch.setBorder(null);
    btnSearch.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    btnSearch.setBounds(185, 210, 87, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnSearch);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\ITC302-Core Java\\java_workspace\\Pictures\\download.jpg"));
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setBounds(270, 202, 290, 215);
    contentPane.add(label);

    JLabel bookIcon = new JLabel("");
    bookIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\ITC302-Core Java\\java_workspace\\Pictures\\BookIcon.png"));
    bookIcon.setBounds(101, 78, 116, 90);
    contentPane.add(bookIcon);

    JLabel lookBookIcon = new JLabel("");
    lookBookIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\ITC302-Core Java\\java_workspace\\Pictures\\image.png"));
    lookBookIcon.setBounds(213, 74, 290, 135);
    contentPane.add(lookBookIcon);
}

public void btnSearchActionPerformed (ActionEvent e, String searchText) {

    DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
    results = db.selectMatchedData(searchText, conn);


    //if (results.length != 0) {
        this.dispose();
        Student_SearchList window = new Student_SearchList();
        window.setVisible(true);
    //}
    //else {
        //Student_Warning window = new Student_Warning();
        //window.setVisible(true);
    //}
}
```

}

And this is where I want to connect my Database:

```
        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
    btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String temp = new String(searchBox.getText());
            btnSearchActionPerformed(e, temp);
        }
    });
```

This whole code is my Main.java.

Comment: What is your question / problem?

Comment: Just comment if you need to look at my full main.java

Comment: PM 77-1 my question is, how will I connect my database to that JFrame. I can't seem to connect it. I am out of answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "*connecting*" a database to a Swing container?

Comment: @PM77-1 I mean, being able for my Search Button in my GUI to connect to my Database in order for it to look for the specific author,book,etc.

Comment: @PM77-1 and my main problem is that it can't proceed to the preparedStatement for DB because it is returning a null connection.

Comment: You do it in a normal `JDBC` way unless you decide to use JPA-based framework (like Hibernate).

Comment: What is inside `DBConnect()`?

Comment: Where's `con` defined and how?

Comment: @PM77-1 I have edited my question and posted my whole main method. The inside of DBConnect() is the connection to the Database itself.

Comment: What does `selectMatchedData()` do and where it's defined?